# Angular2 typescript - print pretty XML

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, typescript, pretty-print

I have this following XML string I got from the server:

```
<find-item-command xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" find-method="Criteria" item-class="com" only-id="false" xsi:schemaLocation=""> <criteria> <criterion> <descriptors> <descriptor>DPSystemEventItem</descriptor> </descriptors> <value>cluster.manager.active</value> </criterion> </criteria> </find-item-command>
```

But I want to beautify it in my module:

```
<find-item-command
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" find-method="Criteria" item-class="com" only-id="false" xsi:schemaLocation="">
    <criteria>
        <criterion>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>DPSystemEventItem</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
            <value>cluster.manager.active</value>
        </criterion>
    </criteria>
</find-item-command>
```

What is the best way to print it beautified?

Answer (score 21):

You can create a custom pipe for this that uses [vkbeautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vkbeautify) under the hoods.

```
npm install -S vkbeautify
```

Custom `xml` pipe example:

```
import * as vkbeautify from 'vkbeautify';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name: 'xml'
})
export class XmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): string {
        return vkbeautify.xml(value);
    }
}
```

Declare the custom pipe in your app.module, e.g.:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { XmlPipe } from '...';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ...,
        ...,
        XmlPipe
    ],
    ...
```

And then you can use the custom pipe in your templates like so:

```
<pre>{{xmlString | xml}}</pre>
```

Comment: This also worked for me. I used Prism.js to get syntax highlighting.

Comment: cannot find module 'vkbeautify', can anyone help

Comment: PSA: usage of the `pre` tag is *mandatory* for it to show up properly in HTML, I was stuck on this for a long time not knowing this!

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the same of @Saeb Amini and getting "**Could not find a declaration file for module**". I run the command

```
npm install -D @types/vkbeautify
```

and then it works fine