# Displaying pretty XML in Angular using string interpolation

Tags: angular, xml, angular8, pretty-print, string-interpolation

I want to display a huge XML on the HTML page using Angular 8. I have using an external package to properly format the `XML` (with proper indentation and line breaks), however, XML appears in one line on the UI when I use string interpolation. It appear properly when I use the `<pre>` tag, but then it ignores my `CSS`.

Is there a way to display properly formatted XML along with CSS styles on it?

Comment: Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42268268/1009922)?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I saw that, but, even in that solution <pre> is being used. When I use <pre> my CSS doesn't get applied. How do I deal with that?

Comment: Can you change your CSS so that it is applied to `pre` elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to preserve line breaks in <code> block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011641/how-to-preserve-line-breaks-in-code-block)